# Getting compile error while using format-date() method in XSLT

Tags: xslt, compiler-errors, formatdatetime

I am trying to convert a XML to CSV using XSLT with version 2.0. But I get a compile error while using format-date method in XSLT. 
Following is the error:

> Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(format-date, [variable-ref(dt/string), literal-expr([D01]/[M01]/[Y0001])])'.
>   FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'.

XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
            extension-element-prefixes="date" date:doc="http://www.exslt.org/date">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">    
<xsl:variable name="dt" select="'2013-04-04'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-date($dt, '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')" />  
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')" />               

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable $dt is a string, not a date. You need to convert it to a date using xs:date('2013-04-04') before you can format it.

Comment: Getting the same error even after converting it to date, I get the same error when I use "current-date()" as well. I am not sure if I am missing something. I get this compile error when I try to use date functions in XSLT. Without date functions my XSL code works fine. I am using Version 2.0

Comment: Perhaps you are not using version 2.0. Sometimes people imagine that just writing version="2.0" in the stylesheet will automatically turn the XSLT processor into a 2.0 processor. How are you running the transformation?

Comment: I am using "javax.xml.transform" transformer with java code.  I want to convert the date time returned from "System.currentTimeMillis()" method to user readable format like ""MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"".
Value returned from "System.currentTimeMillis()" (For Example: 1364969832764) is written to XML and then I am trying to convert this to date time format through XSLT.

Comment: Do something like `<xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/></xsl:comment>` to check your XSLT processor. Chances are you are using the built-in processor, which is XSLT 1.0, and need to put Saxon on the classpath.

Comment: I tried this and identified that I am using XSLT 1.0. I could download saxson9he.jar and run the format-date method in XSLT 2.0 through command line. But when I tried with eclipse I am getting the error: “javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found”. Could you please let me know how to use saxon while working with eclipse and JAVA and when the project is mavenized. I have added the dependency in POM and updated code with tSystem.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");

Comment: It's just a question of having Saxon on the classpath, which means getting your Eclipse configuration right. I'm not an Eclipse expert (still less a maven expert) so I can't give you blow-by-blow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (using Saxon):

```
<xsl:variable name="dt">2013-04-04</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: The reason this works is that the variable is an XML document node, which is atomized to create an untypedAtomic value, and an untypedAtomic value when passed to a function is automatically converted to the required type (xs:date). However convenient, this is a roundabout and inefficient way of accomplishing the goal.