# XSLT takes escape sequences as parameter

Tags: xslt, saxon

Hi I have an stylsheet that that takes a parameter from an `ant xslt task`. But the parameter is full of escape sequences such as `&lt;tag-name&gt;` etc...
Here is the raw representation of the parameter `$fileset-xml`: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vtd9WI81S4Yw__LwzuJoVCfHc4fmXpDrMh9ocGgjUjI/edit?usp=sharing) which is a direct output from this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="fileset-xml"/>
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <xsl:template match="/theRoot">
        <root>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fileset-xml"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My intention is to produce an output in xml format, out of that parameter, but the function `saxon:parse($fileset-xml)` doesn't like the argument in this format. I guess that if we replace the escape characters with their rendered values I will get a valid xml file, but how to do that?

The processor is `saxonb9-1-0-8j`

***EDITION_1***

As an apendx to the comment of @MartinHonnen :

Processor:

`<classpath location="../../infrastructure/SaxonEE9-7-0-11J/saxon9ee.jar:/net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>`

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="fileset-xml"/>
    <xsl:variable name="file-set-xml" select="parse-xml(parse-xml-fragment('&lt;a/&gt;'))"/>
    <!--  -->
    <!--  -->
    <xsl:template match="/theRoot">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$file-set-xml"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the error:

`[xslt] : Fatal Error! Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(parse-
xml-fragment, [literal-expr(<a/>)])'. Cause: Error checking type of the expressi
on 'funcall(parse-xml-fragment, [literal-expr(<a/>)])'.`

Comment: So which error message exactly do you get with `saxon:parse($fileset-xml)`?

Comment: That error message doesn't come from Saxon. With a previous question reporting a very similar error message here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812382/getting-compile-error-while-using-format-date-method-in-xslt it emerged that the problem was that the user was actually running Xalan.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply a string in the form `&lt;a/&gt;` (10 characters), then the XPath function `parse-xml-fragment()` will turn this into the string `<a/>` (4 characters), and if you apply `parse-xml()` (or `parse-xml-fragment()`) to this 4-character string, you will get a node tree containing an empty element named "a".

So you need to parse the data twice.

Comment: Kau
You mean apply as an argument? Because when I apply it as an argument I get an error.

Comment: @Hairi, can you switch to Saxon 9.7 and `version="3.0"`? Then doing `parse-xml(parse-xml-fragment($fileset-xml))` should work. I don't remember whether Saxon B 9.1 has an extension function to parse a fragment string, and you need that for the first parsing step)

Comment: @Michael Kay
I could but then I can not use `saxon:parse` to obtain nodeset out of the string :(

Comment: @Hairi, if you switch to Saxon 9.7 (any edition) and set `version="3.0"` in the XSLT then you don't need an extension function, instead you can use the standard XPath functions `parse-xml(parse-xml-fragment($fileset-xml))`

Comment: @MartinHonnen
Please see the edited original post. Still getting an error.

Comment: @Hairi, why are you now trying to process a string built in the XML? If you have the string literal `'&lt;a/&gt;'` inside your XSLT code and then call `parse-xml-fragment` on it you (in plain XPath) use `parse-xml-fragment('<a/>')` which gives you an XML element that does not need any further parsing. But your original question suggests you have the double escaping outside of XML and based on that Michael Kay suggested you need two parsing steps `parse-xml(parse-xml-fragment($fileset-xml))` so try that on the data as originally fed to your code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Either way I get the same error. No matter which one is the argument `$file-set` or `&lt;a/&gt;`

Comment: @Hairi, the comment by Michael Kay suggests the error you have cited is not coming from Saxon at all so it is hard to tell what exactly goes on.